# LINQ Select with a method that returns a type - creating a new list

Tags: c#, linq

I am a mere beginner and I am trying to learn a bit of LINQ. I have a list of values and I want to receive a different list based on some computation. For example, the below is often quoted in various examples across the Internet:

```
IEnumerable<int> squares = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x * x);
```

here the "computation" is done by simply multiplying a member of the original list by itself.

I wanted to actually use a method that returns a string and takes x as an argument.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
namespace mytests{

    class program {

        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<string> nums = new List<string>();
            nums.Add("999");
            nums.Add("888");
            nums.Add("777");
            
            IEnumerable<string> strings = nums.AsEnumerable().Select(num => GetStrings(num));
            Console.WriteLine(strings.ToString());

        }

        private static string GetStrings (string num){

            if (num == "999")
                return "US";
            else if (num == "888")
            {
                return "GB";
            }
            else
            {
                return "PL";
            }
            
        }

    }
}
```

It compiles but when debugging, the method GetStrings is never accessed and the strings object does not have any members. I was expecting it to return "US", "GB", "PL".

Any advice on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<string>.ToString()` method does not work as you expected. Result will be

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

If you want to see the values which are held in the collection, you should create iteration.

```
foreach (var i in strings) 
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

This line does two things for you. One of them is writing the values which are held in the collection to console. The other operation is iterating the collection. During iteration, values are needed and linq will execute the necessary operation (in your case `GetStrings` method).

Currently your code does not use the collection values, so the code does not evaluate the values and does not trigger `GetStrings` method.

Comment: thank you! This helps me in two ways:

1 - I had no idea the code is not evaluated before it's used, and that explains why adding a watch to the strings var does not show the expected values

2 - how tostring actually works.

Thanks!!

Comment: #1 is what is called _deferred execution_ and it's one of the main peculiarity of Linq: more or less all Linq methods working on collections are implemented with deferred execution